# Docker overlay with HAProxy

Tags: docker, haproxy

I have a QA environment in which I run all my applications and HAProxy on the same overlay network.
I want HAProxy to be able to start without the servers being necessarily up so my server configuration is for example:

```
backend cirrus
    option      httpclose
    option      forwardfor
    balance     leastconn

    server cirrus01 cirrus-bos01:6021 check init-addr none
```

notice the `init-addr none` which allows me to disable initial dns resolution.
Problem with this configuration is that all servers are marked as unhealthy and they never become healthy so I always get NOSRV:

```
2018-12-05T16:50:42+00:00localhost haproxy[12]: 192.168.10.118:64813 
[05/Dec/2018:16:50:42.981] main cirrus/<NOSRV>
0/-1/-1/-1/0 503 212 - - SC-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
{cirrus.docker-app.qa01.company.com|} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

even though the url `cirrus-bos01` IS available from the container itself.

Now if I were to remove the `check init-addr none` from the server definition, haproxy would crash for services I haven't deployed yet:

```
[ALERT] 338/165450 (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:347] : 'server renderer' : could not resolve address 'ytuploader'.
[ALERT] 338/165450 (1) : Failed to initialize server(s) addr.
```

Because there really isn't a server named `ytuploader` yet.

Is there a docker/haproxy solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
I changed the server definition from

```
server cirrus01 cirrus-bos01:6021 check init-addr none
```

to:

```
server cirrus01 cirrus-bos01:6021 check init-addr last,libc,none
```

Comment: bingo. reference: https://github.com/haproxytech/dataplaneapi/issues/54